# Can I use hot module replacement with webpack but not use react?

Tags: webpack

I tried using hot module replacement but never succeed.
Then I found this [repository](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-boilerplate), it can use hot module replacement well. And it uses a react-hot loader, if I remove this loader, I'll get the error:

```
[HMR] Cannot find update. Need to do a full reload!
```

I adjust my project according to the above repository, but I'm not using react, so I don't use react-hot loader, thus I always get the above error.

Can I use hot module replacement with webpack but not use react? Or I just need a xx-hot loader to make it hot module replaceable?

My structure:

```
src
    entry.js
index.html
server.js
webpack.config.js
```

index.html：

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="/static/bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

entry.js：

```
document.write('hello');
```

server.js：

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
var config = require('./webpack.config');

new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), {
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
  hot: true,
  historyApiFallback: true
}).listen(3000, 'localhost', function (err, result) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

  console.log('Listening at localhost:3000');
});
```

webpack.config.js：

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'eval',
    entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        "./src/entry.js"
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "build"),
        publicPath: '/static/',
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ]
};
```

Comment: Try to change your output by `publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/static/'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is required in the entrypoint for HMR to work. It will be removed by minification in prod as its 'unreachable' code

```
if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept();
}
```

Comment: Put it in the "entrypoint" eg first file where you "import" the other modules. This will be defined as (one of) your entry array in your Webpack config, eg:  entry: [
    './js/client.js',
  ], Webpack will start there and build the bundle

Comment: Yes! This question was asked so long ago, haha. I haven't been using webpack for a really long time, but recently I read the document again, and when I read the [Enabling HMR](https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement#enabling-hmr) part, it reminded me of this question. This time I figured out how to make hmr work instantly, just like you answered need to do some work in the entry file. It's really a strange feeling I suddenly figured out a 3 years ago question and I'm so curious why 3 years ago I didn't figure out it. Maybe at that time the document wasn't so detailed?

Answer (score 2):

In short - yes you can.

But you'll need to write code that determines what to do when a module is hot-replaced.

The reason you might be coming across React (and Redux) a lot in your searches for HMR, is that they make HMR easy. In a React & Redux-based app, the vast majority of the code consists of stateless functions (many of them pure, or pure enough), with all of the application state in a single store. This makes it very easy to hot-swap out all kinds of code, and then just re-render the components based on the old state.

The [webpack HMR API](https://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement.html) itself isn't that complicated. The hard part is figuring out how to structure and tool your own code so that bits of it can be safely hot-swapped at runtime. If you're using a popular library or framework, that work may have already been done for you (as it has for React and Redux), otherwise you'll need to do it yourself. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

To support HMR, your module should define - at least - `module.hot.accept` to True. The [documentation](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/hot-module-replacement-with-webpack) also  defines an Api to describe how your module should be reloaded that you might need to implement. Maybe you could have a look to the React Hot Loader to see how they have done it.